# Copying file to shared drive fails in ASP.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, copy

I have ASP.Net and C# application. I am uploading images to the site and store them in the `C:\Images` directory, which works fine.  When I save images to the `C:\Images` folder and simultaneously copy (or some times move) to the *shared* drive, I use the *shared* drive physical address, which looks like `\\192.xxx.x.xx\some folder\Images`. This drive is mapped to the deployment server. I am using IIS hosting for the site.

The problem is with the *shared* drive copying. When I use the site from local machine (where the site is deployed) that copies the file to the *shared* drive. But when I use the site from another machine (other than the deployed server) that saves the image in `C:\Images`, but it won't copy the file to the *shared* drive.

Here's the code I'm using

**Loggedon method shows success in debug.

```
  public static void CopytoNetwork(String Filename)
    {
        try
        {

            string updir = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhysicalPath"].ToString();

            WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;
            IntPtr userHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
            const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
            String UserName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server_UserName"].ToString();
            String Password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server_Password"].ToString();
            String DomainName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server_Domain"].ToString();


            bool loggedOn = LogonUser(UserName, DomainName, Password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref userHandle); 
            try
            {
                File.Move(@"C:\Images\" + Filename, updir + "\\" + Filename);
             }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                if (impersonationContext != null)
                {
                    impersonationContext.Undo();
                }

                if (userHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    CloseHandle(userHandle);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at the exceptions it's throwing.

Comment: Make sure the user under which your application is running has the proper permissions to write to the shared drive.

Comment: it doesn't through any exception. i have tested that also.

Comment: @kaptan : i have tried with admin user and other user also shows the same problem

Comment: have you checked to make sure the server can actually see the up dir (\\192.xxx.x.xx\some folder\Images)?  depending on your network setup, it won't have the same access.

Comment: Comment out the catch (Exception) {} - boo btw.; retry and tell us what exception does it throw.

Comment: @WarpWars.Net : if that doesn't have the access then how that works on deployed machine. (i have tested this on my development machine and Hosted machine by using client and server vice verse) not working.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar : That is not throwing any exception. simply pointer moves bellow. without any exception. :(

Comment: You have two empty catch blocks. Get rid of them all and never use them again.

Comment: This copying work when i run the site in debug mode, then why its not working when i host this in IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up an impersonated user class like this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;

public class ImpersonatedUser : IDisposable
{
    IntPtr userHandle;
    WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;

    public ImpersonatedUser(string user, string domain, string password)
    {
        userHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool loggedOn = LogonUser(
            user,
            domain,
            password,
            LogonType.Interactive,
            LogonProvider.Default,
            out userHandle);

        if (!loggedOn)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        // Begin impersonating the user
        impersonationContext = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(userHandle);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (userHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            CloseHandle(userHandle);
            userHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            impersonationContext.Undo();
        }
    } 

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool LogonUser(
        string lpszUsername,
        string lpszDomain,
        string lpszPassword,
        LogonType dwLogonType,
        LogonProvider dwLogonProvider,
        out IntPtr phToken
        );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hHandle);

    enum LogonType : int
    {
        Interactive = 2,
        Network = 3,
        Batch = 4,
        Service = 5,
        NetworkCleartext = 8,
        NewCredentials = 9,
    }

    enum LogonProvider : int
    {
        Default = 0,
    }
}
```

When you need to do the file copying you do it like this:

```
    using (new ImpersonatedUser(<UserName>, <UserDomainName>, <UserPassword>))
    {
        DoYourFileCopyLogic();
    }
```

Comment: You usually don't want to do this.

Comment: @N. Jensen : Thanks for trying. other just wasting their time in comments. nice try bro!

Comment: @Avi You are absolutely right. We are wasting our time.

Comment: this works prefect to copy file to network drive folder. Thank you very much!:)